# Is SID Filtering Enabled?

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

I ran `nltest /domain_trusts` and received the following output:

```
List of domain trusts:
    ...
    1: TESTLAB TESTLAB.COM (NT 5) (Direct Outbound) ( Attr: 0x8 )
```

I don't understand the attribute field. From this output can you tell if this is an external trust, and if SID filtering is enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SID Filtering (quarantine) would have the 0x4 flag set.

If you want a plain english output, use the following command:

```
netdom trust somedomain.com /domain:anotherdomain.com /quarantine
SID filtering is not enabled for this trust. All SIDs presented in an
authentication request from this domain will be honored.
```

[MS-ADTS]: Active Directory Technical Specification
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223122.aspx